# Trying to open select2 on page load gives the error “The select2('open') method was called on an element that is not using Select2.”

Tags: jquery, django, django-autocomplete-light

Trying to open the select2 on page load using document.ready doesn't work because "autocomplete_light.js initialize function" is tied to same event and at document.ready, the componente isn't initialized yet.

So, doing as below doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select2_field').select2('open')
    //OR
    $('#select2_field').open()
});
```

The problem is that django autocomplete_light initializes the field on document.ready too. I need to open and focus the field on page load, same event. When I try to do so, it gives the error: The select2('open') method was called on an element that is not using Select2. If I access the method on another event, after document.ready, it works.

So, the question is, how can I open the select2 on page load, after it has been initialized by autocomplete light? Autocomplete light doesn't have any callback that I could use.

Comment: I think you can actually register [your callback](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/src/dal/static/autocomplete_light/autocomplete_light.js#L8), but it may require some work. Jquery, not my forte.

Comment: Thanks, Melvyn. 
I think the callback you can register in there gets executed before the initialization of the select2 on the component. Will give it a try anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting an issue on DAL github page, I was guided to add the event notifying after the element initialization and open a pull request myself.

I've done it and now I'm waiting for it to be accepted.

https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/pull/1246